# Have two navigation subforms in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am building a project in Microsoft Access. I have a form with two subforms that are the same, except that they are pulling data whether a value of one of the properties is a or b. I want to get them where you click on one line of data in the subform and it switches to that data in the main form. Basically what i want is a split form with two datasheets as well as the one with the form view. I am new to Access and is it possible to get this behavior?

Comment: You want to emulate a split form. Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/emulating-the-split-form.294421/

Comment: Thank  you. This was just what I was looking for.